# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'restaurant.image')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello Guy I have been having issues with react native,  I kept getting these:
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'restaurant.image')

```
import { View, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles";

const DEFAULT_IMAGE =
  "https://notjustdev-dummy.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uber-eats/restaurant1.jpeg";

const RestaurantHeader = ({ restaurant }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.page}>
      <Image source={{ uri: restaurant.image }} style={styles.image} />

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{restaurant.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>
          $ {restaurant.deliveryFee} &#8226; {restaurant.minDeliveryTime}-
          {restaurant.maxDeliveryTime} minutes
        </Text>

        <Text style={styles.menuTitle}>Menu</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default RestaurantHeader;
```

Comment: It seems might 'restaurant' is null while rendering. Try call his attributes using '?' ..example: restaurant?.image

Comment: Can you log `restaurant` and show us the output?

Comment: Carlos Spohr. Thanks for the help. Your method worked